# How would politics and culture be affected if "in the same country" means "within 300 km of each other"?

Tags: society, culture, politics

I was thinking a world in which there are no national borders between countries and no distinct countries but any two locations that are within 300km of each other are in the same country but any two locations that are more than 300km of each other are in different countries.

How would this setup influence the politics and culture of this world?

Comment: So basically ... Game of Thrones? Some people are loyal to the "king", but most seem to be loyal to their own small part of the country.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense to me. Wouldn't there be an infinite amount of "countries" by this standard? They can't all have distinct laws and cultures.  What is the meaning of "locations that are within 300km of each other are in the same country but any two locations that are more than 300km of each other are in different locations."

Comment: @sumelic I meant, "locations that are within 300km of each other are in the same country but any two locations that are more than 300km of each other are in different countries."  Where I said, "locations," at the end I meant "countries."

Comment: Yeah, but I still don't get what it actually means. "Country" is just a word. You're redefining it. But I have no idea what the use of your new definition is. What practical difference does it make to people in your world if two locations are in the "same" country or in "different" countries?

Comment: If you want a look at the politics of such a small place, take a look at [Switzerland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switzerland) :)

Answer (score 7):

Effectively you would have only a single country, with some weird internal divisions. What does "being in the same country" do for you?

- You have the same currency, trading standards, etc. A pound is a pound, a bushel is a bushel, permissible levels of pesticide are permissible levels. Being "the same" is a [transitive relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation). If A is the same as B and B is the same as C, then A is the same as C. So two places 600 miles apart would both have the same standards as the place halfway in between.
- Related problems for customs duties. Say there are no duties between A and B, and no duties between B and C, but there is a duty between A and C. Traders would simply sell their goods to a shell company in B ...
- Each country has a national legislature to make those standards and regulations. There would have to be an infinite number of legislatures, each for an area with 300 miles diameter, and with overlapping spheres of influence. Impossible, no matter if it is a king who decrees the law or an elected parliament.
- On the other hand, there could be a situation where passports and visa are required to move more than 300 miles from your place of residence. Lots of checkpoints, each with a big map pinned to the wall.

Answer (score 1):

In a society like this it is quite likely that there would be self proclaimed micro-countries formed in the gray areas due to the fact that people there would feel no allegiance towards any one country and more towards their community. This would also affect the culture in that instead of having a common mindset within individual countries, mindsets would be very localized, mostly based on the environment that the people live in and how they grew up. Isolated places on the edges of countries (surrounded by natural obstacles such as deserts and mountains)  would develop their own unique culture,possibly quite similar to a genetic isolation except with cultural practices, and very similar things would happen on islands, although islands would likely be countries with solid borders.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that national borders are the result of political action, and not the cause.  The borders are undefined because nobody can conclusively prevail long enough for the marker stones to get built.

So either the world's denizens despise all non-local governance, such that things like regional and national authorities get put out of business as soon as they make their ambitions known, or the place is so chaotic that nothing can get organized above the local level.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is the premise they "everything within 300 km is my country". Larger cities would have the bigger armies, so they would essentially conquer territory and/or propose (arguably) mutually beneficial agreements (such as protection vs we own you). Your premise translates into "everything within 300 km is mine, and I'll eff you up if you disagree". That would set practical borders which would extend as far as the armies can reach. It wouldn't be clear cut borders, they would move left and right, but there would be a general outline.

Inevitably, such city-states would clash. Either one side would conquer the other, or they'd figure how to coexist. Either way, eventually, that would establish clearly defined borders and alliances. They would start to trade, so they would start establishing standards and develop a common (metaphorical) language to facilitate exchange.

Eventually, they'll have to form an independent, supranational authority to resolve differences and establish the aforementioned standards. Something strictly economical at first, with maybe military protection agreements. It would likely get more political as states become more intertwined.

And then you end up with the European Union.

---

In a nutshell, the first step is city-states with approximate borders. Then it's conflict. Then it's peace talk with the establishment of alliances and borders. Then you end up with federal states. How strong the federal power is will depend on a variety of factors, but there would at least be some form of cooperation. Obviously, it also depends where you are in history.

Answer (score 0):

It does seem difficult to avoid the conclusion that this world must be a single political unit with oddly defined member states.  If you dig in on each country being a fully independent state I can't think of any good reason people would naturally come to regard borders in this fashion, or even continue to regard borders in this fashion for any considerable length of time if they were simply assumed to regard borders in this fashion by hypothesis.  Interstate conflict, if permitted, would soon disrupt border definitions.  So, to maintain the stability of the concept of countryhood, interstate conflict must somehow be suppressed, likely by an overarching world governmental authority.  Then the story would be that this is just how the world government organizes itself, community laws in a spot being governed by those geographically in the community of that spot.  Countries are the top level communities of radius 300 km.  Perhaps there are also lower-level communities with smaller radii that define laws or ordinances within the sphere of authority determined by the overarching authority.  (For example, countries might legislate the definition of violent crimes, but obscenity law could be the purview of "cities", communities of radius 30 km.)  The effect would be a spectrum shift in law as you move from one place to another.  A short drive might offer a bounty of legal pornographic filth, or freedom from the temptation of its open sale, but you'll be driving for quite a while to find a country where the knockout game is a felony instead of the national sport or vice versa.

Having leaders for an undefined number of countries would be tricky, so I think the main two options are direct democracy (with a location's laws being determined by the past votes of voters within the community radius) and autocracy (everyone is dictator of beneath their own feet for life!) The autocratic option is only stable if the power of countries is very, very strictly limited, as it is difficult to see how the countries would not be in constant conflict.

Still, I am intrigued by the question as you posed it, and I think we can get an interesting picture by borging up the population a bit.  Give everyone a neural implant that implements the geographic direct democracy in real time.  If your implant can only communicate with implants within 300km, 300km is the radius of your country.  Interestingly, if we can rule out long range missiles and remote drones, this also eliminates the possibility of international conflict without the need for an overarching supernational authority.  If you have to get within 300 km of someone/something to attack them/it, there simply are no available international targets.  Sending a bomber or soldier into rival territory can only be a transfer of citizenship and equipment.  International relations are effectively limited to trade (by relay or immigration) and teleconference.

I don't think immigration controls as borders could be a thing, everyone would wind up effectively frozen in place (you don't have to move very far to cross SOME border), but you might wind up with prices of entry to move a particular direction.  "If you're coming this way, bring copper."  "If you're coming this way, bring food."  With the neural implant direct democracy, this would be easy.  People in food impoverished countries know they're hungry, and their neural implants vote to not allow people in without food.  (Hopefully you can check the laws of a destination before departing even if your neural implant cannot directly communicate with the implants there.)  Global trade would become very efficient.